# Difference between industrial motherboards and consumer motherboards

Tags: hardware

I need to upgrade a small industrial fanless PC with Thin Mini-ATX form-factor motherboard (Mitac PD10BI), as it's being a bit sluggish as a virtual kiosk.

The upgrade route I have is to get a newer motherboard model from the same manufacturer, which is about 250$.

However, I can see that there are consumer mini-PCs with a much better spec for half the price with RAM, HDD, SSD and a case included!

I appreciate that in some edge cases an industrial motherboard *may* have some special connectors, but this is not the case with this mobo.

Why are industrial motherboards so expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "TLDR" : we on ServerFault can't possibly know why vendors select the particular prices they list. *(Or when somebody here is "in the know" most likely they won't be allowed to disclose such privileged information.)*

Wikipedia lists many different product/service [**pricing strategies & tactics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pricing#Pricing_strategies) that make for interesting reading and background knowledge.

If you’re only looking at connectors you may overlook other  features that mark a motherboard suitable for industrial purposes: a common feature for industrial pc’s and servers are that they support and guarantee to remain operational in much more extreme and adverse environmental conditions , high/low temperature, vibration, humidity, dust and other pollution etc.

You also select more rugged industrial computers for deployments outside of a temperature controlled server room or a nice office.

Comment: To be fair TLDR should be "a common feature for industrial pc’s and servers are that they support and guarantee to remain operational in much more extreme and adverse environmental conditions , high/low temperature, vibration, humidity, dust and other pollution etc.". No need to be nasty

Comment: Nothing in @HBruijn's post (nor its edit history) is "nasty".